# Java: one-liner to add things to a declared File[]?

Tags: java, file

The directoryReader gets you dirs in current dir in File[]-format.

**Code**

```
DirectoryReader data = new DirectoryReader();
File[] dirs = data.getDirsInDir(".");
File[] dirsMore = data.getDirsInDir("..");

// How can I append dirsMore to dirs-file[]?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    File[] concat(File[] A, File[] B) 
   {
     File[] C= new File[A.length+B.length];
     System.arraycopy(A, 0, C, 0, A.length);
     System.arraycopy(B, 0, C, A.length, B.length);
     return C;
   }
```

Heres the doc for java's [arraycopy()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't append to an array.  The simplest way is to put the array into a Collection, do an "addAll" to the other array, and then use "toArray" on the Collection.

```
List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
fileList.addAll(dirs);
fileList.addAll(dirsMore);

File[] allDirs = fileList.toArray(new File[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<File> aList = Arrays.asList(dirs);
List<File> bList = Arrays.asList(dirsMore);

aList.addAll(bList);  // a has all elements
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure a List you get from Arrays.asList can't be appended to.

Comment: thanks , im tried it now and it make exception : 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException